# How to set a Var from inside a Task?

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx-2, javafx, task

First of all I'm new at JavaFX, so sorry if this question is stupid. How can I get an return Object from a Task?

Heres my Problem:

I want to get a List of Objects from a Mock. The Mock has a delay from 1 up to 5 seconds. But I dont want, that my GUI freeze in this time.

In Java.Swing it was easy with an Thread, but JavaFX has, as far as I know, Tasks.

I've read much tutorials, but everywhere they return a text property. So here is my question: how can I set the value of an Object with the result of the calculation from a Task/Thread (in my case a List)

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ray,

You are right in that the examples seem to gloss over getting back results from tasks.  There are two ways that you can get back results that I know of:

1. Through the `getValue()` method of the Task class (this is the way I have done it)
2. Through the `get()` method of the parent FutureTask class (I haven't used this, but in principle it should work).

With the first `getValue()` aproach you need to make sure the task sets the value through the `updateValue(...)` method in the call method of the task.  Then put a listener on the WorkerStateEvent

```
myTask.setOnSucceeded(new EventHandler<WorkerStateEvent>() {

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public void handle(WorkerStateEvent event) {
        ReturnType rt =  (ReturnType) event.getSource().getValue()
        // ... other stuff to do here ...
    }
});
```

The first approach is a little verbose but it works and allows for some more complicated operations after the task has finished.

The second approach is a little simpler and straightforward but doesn't give you as much control over what to do when the task finishes. With the `get()` method of FutureTask, the code should block until the Task returns with the value.  So using it should be as simple as:

```
//
// Start the task in a thread (using whatever approach you like) 
//before calling the get() method.
//
ReturnType rt = myTask.get();
```

I have used `Future` objects with other code, but I have not used `FutureTask` with the FX api, so I can not tell you if there are hidden gotchas in it.

Good luck,

chooks

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I've found a error by my self. I've forget to add an EventHandler if the Task is done. So I've allways called task.getValue() but the Task was still runnig and so the value was null.

Answer (score 2):

The Task is a generic type. That means that if you apply a type to a Task like `Task<Integer>` the Task class will have functions that returns you an Integer. One of this functions is the `valueProperty()`, that can be bind to other scene elements. Being shown in a Label, or whatever. I recommend you to read [the javafx binding tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/binding/jfxpub-binding.htm), to get a better comprehension.

Here is a sample of Task using or their properties.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.concurrent.Task;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.control.ProgressBar;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TestingTasks extends Application{

    public static void main(String[] args) {launch(args);}

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {

        VBox vbox = new VBox(10);
        vbox.setAlignment(Pos.TOP_CENTER);

        ListView<String> list = new ListView<>();
        HBox hbox = new HBox(10);
        hbox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_LEFT);
        Label labelMessage = new Label();
        hbox.getChildren().addAll(new Label("Message: "), labelMessage);
        ProgressBar progress = new ProgressBar(-1);
        progress.setVisible(false);

        Button button = new Button("Executing Task");
        button.setOnAction(event(button, list, progress, labelMessage));

        vbox.getChildren().addAll(list, hbox, button, progress);
        Scene scene = new Scene(vbox, 400, 300);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    private EventHandler<ActionEvent> event(final Button button, final ListView<String> list, final ProgressBar progress, final Label labelMessage) {       
        return new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                Task<ObservableList<String>> task = generateTask();
                list.itemsProperty().bind(task.valueProperty());
                progress.visibleProperty().bind(task.runningProperty());
                labelMessage.textProperty().bind(task.messageProperty());
                button.disableProperty().bind(task.runningProperty());
                task.runningProperty().addListener(listenerRunningTask());
                Thread t = new Thread(task);
                t.setDaemon(true);
                t.start();
            }

        };
    }

    private Task<ObservableList<String>> generateTask() {               
        return new Task<ObservableList<String>>() {                 
            @Override
            protected ObservableList<String> call() throws Exception {
                updateMessage("Waiting...");
                Thread.sleep(5000);
                updateMessage("Waking up");
                return FXCollections.observableArrayList("One", "Two", "Three");
            }
        };
    }   

    private ChangeListener<? super Boolean> listenerRunningTask() {     
        return new ChangeListener<Boolean>() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> observable, Boolean oldValue, Boolean newValue) {
                if(oldValue && !newValue){
                    //TODO when finish
                }               
            }
        };
    }   
}
```

So basically, you can return a variable in the Task, or wait the Task ends and execute something, create your own bindings...

If you want to modify something of the screen from the thread, you need to do it from the FX Thread, the Task function call is outside the FX Thread, for that reason the screen it isn't freeze. But all the bind elements will occur in the FX Thread, so are safe to modify the GUI.

If you want to modify safely the GUI from a not FX Thread, just do:

```
Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {                  
    @Override
    public void run() {
        //Safe modification in the FX Thread
    }
});
```

Also take a look on [concurrency in JavaFX2](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/threads/jfxpub-threads.htm). This explain more deeply the concurrency, Service, Task...

Hope it helps!